# What exactly does it mean by pencil in this context?

Tags: elliptic-curves, projective-geometry

I wanted to clarify some terminology. I am writing a project on elliptic curves and a document I am following mentions the following:

> The cubics through ${P_1,...,P_8}$ form a pencil,
> $$\lambda_1\Gamma_1 + \lambda_2\Gamma_2$$

am I correct in thinking this is essentially saying that we can find two linearly independent cubics ${\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2}$ which pass through ${P_1,...,P_8}$ such that any other cubic passing through ${P_1,...,P_8}$ can be written as a linear combination of ${\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_(geometry) (specifically, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_(geometry)#Pencil_of_conics )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  In fact $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$ can be any two cubics passing through those points.

More at [cut-the-knot.org](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/PencilOfCubics.shtml)